# Any smart way/algorithm to find what changed in html structure? (React.js microsoft OneNote api)

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, onenote, rte

I'm writting a web app which will have some OneNote functionality. But i've encountered some problem. In order to updata a page, OneNote API requires to send array of changes in format like this:

```
[
 {
   'target':'#div1',
   'action':'append',
   'position':'before',
   'content':'<img data-id="first-child" src="image-url-or-part-name" />'
},
{
   'target':'#div1',
   'action':'append',
   'content':'<p data-id="last-child">New paragraph appended to the div</p>'
}
]
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-update-page

So if using text editor, such as react-rte (npm library) how am i supposed to find my changes in format like that? Do i have to create some algorith myself and compare starting and final content to find out what changed?

Comment: maybe try https://draftjs.org/ which has very nifty features for tracking changes

Answer (score 1):

A Naive solution could be for you to update the whole page by using target "body" - basically:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-update-page

```
[
 {
   'target':'body',
   'action':'replace'
   'content':'...'
}
]
```

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking about that, but haven't tried that yet.. Wonder if it will work, thanks though...

Comment: I think it should ;)

Comment: I've tried the solution. Works very randomly... Idk, it's quite hard to use their api. For example, if i get response
<body>
<div> some content </div>
<div> another div content </div>
</body>
Sometimes replacing whole body edits only first div.... Damn, such a headache task...  I've also tried just selecting all parent divs (inside body ) and replace them invidually, but that still... sometimes this doesn't work... I wish i could find decent(REAL) example of their API usage